# Reflection of HTML elements - django

Tags: django, django-templates, lazy-loading

I am trying to give an administrator of the webservice an ability to name buttons of the main menu using whathever text he or she wants. Moreover, I want to allow him to play with styles that particular button will be described with.

Each of written above action should be available from the administrator's menu ( in this case it is a default django admin framework ).

I've came up with an idea of using completely new model:

```
class MainSiteButton(models.Model):
    button_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        null=True, 
        blank=False, 
        default="Click to edit",
        verbose_name="Text of the button"
    )

    button_style = models.CharField(
        max_length=10000, 
        null=True, 
        blank=False, 
        default="font-size: 10px; font-color: green;",
        verbose_name="Style of the button"
    )

    button_default_name = models.CharField(
        choices=button_default_name_choices,
        max_length=500, 
        null=True, 
        blank=False, 
        default=next(iter(button_default_name_choices))[0],
        verbose_name="Button back-end identifier"
    )
```

Using given model, I am going to define each button, that is defined in the webpage's menu.

These will have such a form:

```
queried_home_button = MainSiteButton.objects.create(
    button_title="Home",
    button_default_name='home_button'
)
queried_logout_button = MainSiteButton.objects.create(
    button_title="Logout",
    button_default_name='logout_button'
)
queried_login_button = MainSiteButton.objects.create(
    button_title="Login",
    button_default_name='login_button'
)
```

Operation of defining new buttons will occur only once, at a start of the server

Another step is to define a lazy context processor:

```
@memoize
def texts_of_buttons(request):
    context_data = dict()

    try:

        queried_home_button = MainSiteButton.objects.filter(
            button_default_name='home_button'
        )[0]
        queried_logout_button = MainSiteButton.objects.filter(
            button_default_name='logout_button'
        )[0]
        queried_login_button = MainSiteButton.objects.filter(
            button_default_name='login_button'
        )[0]

        context_data['home_button'] = queried_home_button
        context_data['logout_button'] = queried_logout_button
        context_data['login_button'] = queried_login_button

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            'Problem: exception occured in MainSubPageController'
            + '\nError: ' + str(texts_of_buttons)
        )

    return context_data
```

To finally use it in the base template:

```
<a class="item {{ home_button.button_style|safe }}" href="{% url 'home' %}">{{ home_button.button_title }}</a>
<a class="item {{ queried_login_button.button_style|safe }}" href="{% url 'login' %}">{{ queried_login_button.button_title }}</a>
<a class="item {{ queried_logout_button.button_style|safe }}" href="{% url 'logout' %}">{{ queried_logout_button.button_title }}</a>
```

The question arises whether there exist better solution ( which means faster, that requires fewer memory resources

Comment: This is actually *not* lazy. Since if you "index" a queryset (like `qs[1]`) you perform evaluation.

Comment: that's correct, but I simply thought that using 'memoize' decorator along with function defined here: https://rock-it.pl/how-to-make-your-django-context-processors-lazy/ the result of this context processor is stored in the memory.
Thanks for making it clear